# Automatically replace user passwords in mysql db dump on server side (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, bash, laravel, laravel-5

**Use Case**

To setup a development environment one needs a mysql dump of the application database. The dump origin is the production database.

**Problem**

I do not want to give the dump to anyone since it contains the (hashed) user passwords.

**Solution Idea**

Replace all user passwords (one password for all users for dev purpose would be ok) on the server side before giving access to the dump.

**Environment**

- Laravel application
- MySQL database
- The bash script could run over Capistrano or be executed on the server via ssh manually

Any ideas how to solve this in a smart way?

**Example dump (only users table)**

```sql
# ************************************************************
# Sequel Pro SQL dump
# Version 4541
#
# http://www.sequelpro.com/
# https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro
#
# Host: 127.0.0.1 (MySQL 5.7.12)
# Datenbank: app
# Erstellt am: 2017-01-04 14:22:35 +0000
# ************************************************************


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


# Export von Tabelle users
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_tenant_id_role_unique` (`email`,`tenant_id`,`role`),
  KEY `users_tenant_id_index` (`tenant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_tenant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_id`) REFERENCES `tenants` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `role`, `tenant_id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (1,'admin',1,'appadmin','admin@example.com','123$15$g4qKHcS7zHercuNJobfFxOTWGoW7YN.tphFdddGIIEXkrkE8Etxxx',NULL,'2017-01-04 14:19:04','2017-01-04 14:19:04');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Please add sample dump (replace hashed passwords by same number of random characters) and your desired output for that sample dump to your question.

Comment: easiest way is to load the db to your local server, update passwords, create second dump.

Comment: @Cyrus I added an example dump (only the users table of the database)

Comment: @VasilShaddix I search for an automated solution…

Comment: Over what part of the process do you have control? By that, I mean, what parts are you capable of changing? Can you dictate what gets dumped in the first place? Or, are you stuck with a text dump and you need to scrub that file? Additionally: What OS are you on? Does it need to be only done with bash? How many records are we talking about?

Comment: Are the columns able to be nulled? What's stopping you from simply setting them to the hashed value of `password`? You can predetermine that value and then update it automatically. I'm not really sure what's actually stopping you here

Comment: Are you sure it's safe to hand the developers emails, other user data? Why not create something to fake up a load of data in the correct format for development purposes? Google 'database seeding'

Comment: The way I’d do it is to restore the dump as it is into an intermediate, private database (better not on the production server), replace sensitive data with a couple of `UPDATE users` commands, and give the developers a dump of the modified database. All of this can be automated with a simple bash script, if the database is not too big and you have an intermediatte server at hand... What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i recommend doing it the sql-way:

```
create table users_tmp like users;
insert into users_tmp select * from users;
update users_tmp set password='whatever';
```

then after import

```
rename table users_tmp to users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple **Command** to replace all (non-admin) email addresses and passwords in the Users table, then dump the database. The password protected Command below changes all email addresses that are do not use the given domain, and then changes the passwords for all accounts. At the end of the `fire` method, add your artisan command to dump the database. (Assuming you already have a package for this).

```
class RelacePasswordsAndEmailsCommand extends Command {
    protected $name = 'mycommand/safe_user_dump';
    protected $description = 'Changes all email addresses and passwords for a safe dump';
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire() {
        if ($this->confirm('WARNING! This will change all email addresses and passwords in the database. Do you wish to continue? [yes|no]')) {
            $password = $this->secret('What is the password?');
            if ( $password === 'mysecretpassword' ) {
                $emails = DB::table('users')
                    ->where(function ($q) {
                        return $q->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@example.com');
                    })->lists('id');
                foreach ($emails as $id ) {
                    DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(['email' => 'user' . $id . '@example.com']);
                }
                DB::table('users')->update(['password' => 'myhashpassword'])

                $this->info( count($emails) . ' email addresses and passwords changed.');

                # Add your database dump command here

            } else {
                $this->info('The password was incorrect.');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this would override the production data, you are missed a intermediate step, or?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that you should run this after copying the database to the staging server.

Answer (score 1):

Use case:

- You can do a dump of production DB, import the DB into test/stage env and update User table.
  SQL for User anonymization:

  ```
  UPDATE User
  SET
    mobile_phone  = NULL,
    private_phone = NULL,
    email = IF(isnull(email), NULL, concat('user', id, '@test.local')),
    password = MD5('code')
  ;
  ```
- Developers should only dump the DB from the test/stage env.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using mysqldump options
   `mysqldump -d app` - dump all without data
   `mysqldump -t --ignore-table=app.users app` - dump data only but exclude users table
2. Search for password pattern in dump file and replace it, for example, using linux sed:
   `sed -i 's/'\''\$2y\$[0-9]\{2\}\$.\{53\}'\''/'\''new-hash-here'\''/g' dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

i'm not fluent in console environment regex. but wouldn't it be better to dump data, then do something of the sort

```
(^\s*\([0-9]+,'.*',[0-9]+,'.*','.*',)'.*'(,.*,.*,.*\))
```

and replace with

```
\1'NEW_HASH'\2
```

[image: tested out in notepad++]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`strike`](https://github.com/wuakitv/strike), a command-line script wrapper for [`my_obfuscate`](https://github.com/mavenlink/my_obfuscate), which is a library designed for obfuscating SQL dumps.

First, install the `strike` utility (Requires `ruby` to be installed on the system):

```
gem install strike
```

Next, run `strike obfuscate` to obfuscate your dump. The following example will replace all `password` values in the `users` table with the fixed string `"password"`:

```
strike obfuscate \
  -p <(echo 'table(:users){|t| t.password type: :fixed, string: "password"}') \
  < dump.sql
```

Note: Because the library performs line-by-line parsing, it will only work if the `INSERT INTO`users`() VALUES ()` command is on a single line, like so:

```
 INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `role`, `tenant_id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1,'admin',1,'appadmin','admin@example.com','123$15$g4qKHcS7zHercuNJobfFxOTWGoW7YN.tphFdddGIIEXkrkE8Etxxx',NULL,'2017-01-04 14:19:04','2017-01-04 14:19:04');
```

The output of the `strike obfuscate` command will return the entire SQL dump contents, but with the INSERT line modified to have the `password` value obfuscated:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `role`, `tenant_id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('1','admin','1','appadmin','admin@example.com','password',NULL,'2017-01-04 14:19:04','2017-01-04 14:19:04');
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in a **smart** way would be, well, **don't dump the database**.

For a better viable development environment, you are better with:

- use a schema dump (eg: with `mysqldump --no-data`) **or** schema db migrations (i belive laravel has that built-in) **or** schema spec (if you use for eg: Propel) to create your tables
- use a fixture and/or a console command to populate the database with whatever you need for any development task that is not special (payments or other quirky stuff)
- use a containerization tool such as **docker** and/or **vagrant** (i use both)
- *maybe* you could keep all development environment provisioning details in the main repo, unless you create a special repo for provisioning
- *maybe* create yourself a script that builds/cleans/rebuilds the development environment

This will bring you a great deal of advantages (Eg: you can add the test users credentials in the developer documentation, as well as having other data pre-populated like roles and stuff).

You can use a couple of other solutions presented in here in other answers for a **quick** way.

Comment: I am totally with you that this is the best solution and we have migrations to re-create the schema easily, but no completed db seeders right now thats why I am searching for an alternative (i.e. use the production dump)

Comment: Why not create your own seeder ? You can create a CLI command that seeds a vanilla database. I've done that for a couple of projects and i usually run the command at the end of the provisioning. You can add it to a developer specific sub-namespace (eg: `App\Console\Commands\Dev`). Artisan is based on symfony console with somewhat added sugar, so it should be quite easy.